# Markdown bar is not shown in iOS Safari

Tags: bug, safari, ios

The Markdown bar to do the bold, block quote, code sample, etc. is not showing up, when I use iOS Safari to answer a question.

I can only type plain text, or type four spaces by myself to make the Markdown content.

Is it designed to be like this, or is it a bug?

iOS 12.0 / Safari/604.1

Comment: Which iOS/Safari version are you using?

Comment: edited ! iOS 12.0, safari 604.1

Comment: Technically, you can enter the markdown for any of those things yourself, for instance `**bold**` for **bold**, `*italic*` for *italic*`, a tick mark for an inline code sample, `> ` at the beginning of a line for blockquote, etc. I agree that not having the buttons there is silly though :).

Comment: The markdown bar isn't available in the mobile version of the site as far as I am aware (FYI, this is what the mobile version looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GC3Oc.png ). You can see it in the full (desktop) version of the site. But even though it is responsive, it hasn't taken over the mobile theme as the default theme when viewed in a mobile device.

Comment: FWIW I can see it in desktop mode on OSX Safari 12

Comment: As far as I know the only thing the bar should contain on the mobile version of the site (the one linked from the footer) is the "add picture" item, all other items are not enabled. Do you see the add picture item?